# shape of an output tensor after convolutional filter on a colour image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I find it difficult to understand a notion about tensors.
For VGG (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/VGG16), we start from a batch of colour images (none,224,224,3) and apply 64 2D convolutional filters.
At the output we obtain a tensor of (none,224,224,64), we can see this by making a summary of the model.
However, a filter must treat all 3 colours and my intuition tells me that I should have an output tensor of (none,224,224,3,64).
Could one explain to me why my reasoning is wrong?
Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All filters have shape

```
(kernel_height, kernel_width, input_channels)
```

When they pass on your input data with `'SAME'` padding, the output shape result is

```
(input_height, input_width)
```

And that, for all filters, so

```
(input_height, input_width, n_filters)
```